# Why are my different sorting algorithms resulting in the same run time?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

For CS homework assignment I am to create random arrays of increasing size in java and plot their runtime on a graph. However, my implementations of Insert, Merge, and Quick sort seem to have the same run times when run with the same input. I've implemented them differently many times and am still getting the same results. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*; import java.util.Random;

public class Complexity {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the array size: ");
    int a = input.nextInt(); 
    System.out.println("Enter the number size: ");
    int n = input.nextInt();

    int[] arr = newArr(a, n);
    int[] arr2 = arr.clone();
    int[] arr3 = arr.clone();

//INSERT SORT
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    insertSort(arr);
    long endTime = System.nanoTime();
    long duration = (endTime - startTime)/1000000;
    System.out.println("Insert Sort Time:" + duration + "ms");

//MERGE SORT
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    mergeSort(arr2, 0, a-1);
    long end = System.nanoTime();
    long dur = (end - start)/1000000;
    System.out.println("Merge Sort Time:" + duration + "ms");

//QUICK SORT
    long s = System.nanoTime();
    quickSort(arr3, 0, a-1);
    long e = System.nanoTime();
    long d = (e - s);
    System.out.println("Quick Sort Time:" + duration + "ms");
}


public static int[] newArr(int a, int n) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int newArray[] = new int[a];
     for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
         int number= rand.nextInt(n);
         newArray[i]=number;
     }
    return newArray;
}

public static void quickSort(int[] arr, int low, int high) {
    if(low<high) {
        int pivotIndex = findPivot(arr, low, high);
        quickSort(arr, low, pivotIndex-1);
        quickSort(arr, pivotIndex+1, high);
    }
}

public static int findPivot(int[] arr, int low, int high) {
    int pivot = arr[high];
    int nextSmallest = (low-1);
    for(int currentIndex = low; currentIndex < high; currentIndex++) {
        if(arr[currentIndex] <= pivot) {
            nextSmallest++;
            int temp = arr[nextSmallest];
            arr[nextSmallest] = arr[currentIndex];
            arr[currentIndex] = temp;
        }
    }
    int temp = arr[nextSmallest+1];
    arr[nextSmallest+1] = arr[high];
    arr[high] = temp;
    return nextSmallest+1;
}

public static void mergeSort(int[] arr, int left, int right){
    if(left<right) {
        int middle = (left + right) / 2;
        mergeSort(arr, left, middle);
        mergeSort(arr, middle+1, right);
        merge(arr, left, middle, right);
    }
}

public static void merge(int[] arr, int left, int middle, int right){
    int leftLength = middle - left + 1;
    int rightLength = right - middle;
    int newL[] = new int [leftLength];
    int newR[] = new int [rightLength];
    for (int i=0; i<leftLength; ++i)
        newL[i] = arr[left + i];
    for (int j=0; j<rightLength; ++j)
        newR[j] = arr[middle + 1+ j];
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    int k = left;
    while (i < leftLength && j < rightLength) {
        if (newL[i] <= newR[j]) {
            arr[k] = newL[i];
            i++;
        }
        else {
            arr[k] = newR[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }
    while (i < leftLength) {
        arr[k] = newL[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }
    while (j < rightLength) {
        arr[k] = newR[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
}

static void printArray(int arr[], String methodName) {
        System.out.print(methodName);
    int n = arr.length;
    for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
        System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
    System.out.println();
}

public static void insertSort(int[] arr){
    int temp;
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for(int j = i ; j > 0 ; j--){
            if(arr[j] < arr[j-1]){
                temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j-1];
                arr[j-1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Most likely you are making arrays of too small a size to make a difference. Also you are deleting in integers, which truncates microseconds.

Comment: How large are the inputs? Remember that the time complexity is in asymptotic terms, therefore the input needs to be large to make any difference.

Comment: Related: [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java)

Comment: Seems like you could declare your variables `long start,end,duration;` and just reuse them, instead of declaring new variables with new names each time. And you forgot to divide by 1000000 for quick sort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each of your print statements prints the `duration` from insertion sort instead of `dur` and `d`.